# How to override onCreate method in kotlin in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Hello I am making a app in which when main activity opens a lotte animation plays as a button and when i click on that animation (button) then activity 2 opens and plays a video and when the video get completes i called main activity again using intent, so when main activity opens again i want that now that animation button hides.

I tried to write override onresume and i also tried override onrestart and then i wrote

```
  override fun onRestart() {
        super.onRestart()
        binding.btnanimation.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }
```

but when i do that then when activity opens in starting then also that button animation get hides, but i want that when app opens it must be visible as its called inside oncreate

my onCreate code something like this

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)


        setContentView(binding.root)


        binding.btnanimation.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

Comment: What should happen if user presses back before the video completed? Should the button be visible or invisible?

Comment: after pressing back also it is visible plz help sir

Comment: Make use of shared preferences with Boolean value to keep track of view visibility changes. Refer this documentation : https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Comment: @neha goenka Look like that you are new to android development. If you want, I can help you to master it. Would you like to learn android development from me ?

Comment: @nehagoenka You want the simplest solution? Use `companion object { var visible = true }` inside MainActivity. When the video completes, set `MainActivity.visible = false`. And in onCreate of MainActivity, set `binding.btnanimation.isVisible = visible`. (This is a quick solution that will work but isn't the best way)

Comment: sorry to say but still its not working

Answer (score 0):

add `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` attribute to your MainActivity and don't call finish() on it after starting another activity.

Comment: hey i tried this also its still now working

Comment: Paste the above code in your **AndroidManifiest.xml** under your **MainActivity**

Comment: @nehagoenka if you want the simplest solution then, DM me on [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/x__coder__x/). I will teach you android development for free.

Comment: @nehagoenka Okay, I will soon message you

Comment: @nehagoenka Check your telegram inbox, **ErrorXcode** has messaged you.